# How the multisignature process working after completed the contract process

Tags: web3js, multisignature

I completed a [contract creation process using Ethereum Wallet source code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/how-can-i-create-the-multisignature-address-using-cli-json-rpc-or-web3).

How can I use this contract from a web3 client (not from Mist) ?

Can you give some example workflows for using multisignature process ?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to ethereumJ ? Or did you make a multisig wallet on Mist?

Comment: Sorry i am using the web3js for contract process now i need next step what i need to do

Comment: still not clear what the "process" is, do you have a link or anything?

Comment: compile the source code in this link https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/blob/master/Wallet.sol
and then create the contract for multisignature this work i completed. And i need the next step how access the multisignature code functions

Comment: This question is the following of http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/how-can-i-create-the-multisignature-address-using-cli-json-rpc-or-web3 so don't close it. I edited the question to add the link

Comment: Basically you just use it like all other web3 contract interactions. There is nothing special about it. Just search this site for how to send transactions to a contract in web3js

Comment: can i get one example because the call contract function process is not working to me. i try the simple hello world contract but i can't get the result
i get the code from this link : https://www.ethereum.org/greeter
but the call method "greeter.greet();" is not working